# Firewall blocking DLL on ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, ftpwebrequest, windows-firewall

I have a project which makes a .dll in C# which contains a very simple ftp client (FtpWebRequest, FtpWebResponse), and want to use that .dll in various Web projects including it in Bin directory.

The problem is: Windows Firewall.

A console application using that .dll works fine, because I can make a rule on firewall to let the .exe do the ftp connection.

A web application doesn't work because firewall is blocking it, returning always a WebException Timeout.

Any ideas how to make it work on web applications without disabling windows firewall?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a rule for iis worker process as an exception to windows firewall. It is done in exactly the same way as it is done for the console application.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I have World Wide Web (HTTP) Services rule activated on my firewall to allow others in LAN connect to my IIS server. How exactly do I add the IIS worker process? Can you give me an example please? Tanhk you.

Comment: Sorry but I later realized that you are running FTP Client and any client application is not blocked by windows firewall, just the server applications are blocked. May be your problem is something different. I would recommend you to take a look at windows event log and find out the exact problem.

Comment: No luck! Nothing on logs.    Same .dll works on console application, can't make it work on web application.